# Can the term kaiwa no heya be used to mean an actual location/room to chat in?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I know that the term chattorumu is used for online chats. What term would be used to denote an actual room for this activity?  A room to chat in.

Comment: Does the concept of a physical chat room exist in English...? What is the context of your question?

Comment: I wanted to determine if there was a difference between an online room and a physical location.

Comment: I understand your question itself, but I'm just trying to understand the premise of it. Do you think a physical "chat room" is a well defined concept? I think in English, you wouldn't use "chat room" for a room you chat in, as rooms you chat in often have an overarching and/or broader purpose than just chatting (e.g. a common room, a staff room, a break-out room, a waiting room, a living room). Is there a reason you expect the Japanese language to label the concept of "a room where you chat" specifically?

Comment: I was actually discussing the term kaiwa no heya with a Japanese person. A room where we can talk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I'm not sure whether a real chat room has ever existed in English-speaking world (after a bit of Googling), and I'm not sure it's the perfect match for the hypothetical concept, I know that some facilities actually have 談話室【だんわしつ】 for close or private small-group conversation. [A number of diners](https://tabelog.com/rstLst/?vs=1&sa=&sk=%25E8%25AB%2587%25E8%25A9%25B1%25E5%25AE%25A4&lid=hd_search1&vac_net=&svd=20190811&svt=2100&svps=2&hfc=1&sw=%25E8%25AB%2587%25E8%25A9%25B1%25E5%25AE%25A4) (mostly cafés) seem to have it as a part of the trade name too.

[image]
(from [a random conference hall website](https://www.niigata-kenminkaikan.jp/information/conference/))

Last but not least, this word is also not uncommon for the name of online chatrooms or forums.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Kaiwa no heya is also understood.

Comment: @JACK かいわべや (kaiwabeya) should be way more natural to me, though I don't think it's an established word...